# Displaying Data on the Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, layout

I'm searching files and returning lines that include the search text, and I'm not really sure the best way to display the information I get. Every time I get a match, I want to show, in some sort of control, the File it came from, and the whole text line. (aka `streamreader.ReadLine()` result). First I tried just putting it all in a read-only text box, but it doesn't have a scroll bar.

What is the best form control to help me display this data neatly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text box should do just fine. Just set [`MultiLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12w624ff.aspx) to `true` and [`ScrollBars`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.scrollbars.aspx) to `Auto` (or `Vertical`, whichever suits you best).

Comment: well I had the mutliline. But the other problem is that it doesn't seem to recognize when i add a \n to it.

Comment: @The.Anti.9: did you try adding the text using `yourTextBox.AppendText(lineToAdd + Environment.NewLine);`?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would probably be either a [Listbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.aspx), or a [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx).

Also maybe have a look at [Environment.NewLine Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

A `ListView` will work for this.  Set its `View` property to `Details`, and add two columns in the designer (call them FileName and FirstLine or something, and play around with the widths as you like).

You add a new line like this:

```
string FileName = @"c:\file1.txt";
string FirstLine = "This is the first line of text from the file";
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(FileName);
item.SubItems.Add(FirstLine);
listView1.Items.Add(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list box to list the files in which the text was found, and then, a text box containing the text you want to show. You should be able to work if you do like Fredrik Mörk said.